# How to insert a line between consecutive duplicate lines?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I want to add a dummy IP address but only after two consecutive duplicate lines are  found.

I am working on a Linux system and this is my input file:

```
  IP_Remote_Address
     Address : 192.168.1.1
  IP_Remote_Address
     Address : 192.168.1.2
  IP_Remote_Address
     Address : 192.168.1.3
  IP_Remote_Address
  IP_Remote_Address
     Address : 192.168.1.4
  IP_Remote_Address
     Address : 192.168.1.5
  IP_Remote_Address
     Address : 192.168.1.6
  IP_Remote_Address
     Address : 192.168.1.7
  IP_Remote_Address
  IP_Remote_Address
     Address : 192.168.1.8
```

My desired output:

```
  IP_Remote_Address
     Address : 192.168.1.1
  IP_Remote_Address
     Address : 192.168.1.2
  IP_Remote_Address
     Address : 192.168.1.3
  IP_Remote_Address
     Address : NOT_FOUND
  IP_Remote_Address
     Address : 192.168.1.4
  IP_Remote_Address
     Address : 192.168.1.5
  IP_Remote_Address
     Address : 192.168.1.6
  IP_Remote_Address
     Address : 192.168.1.7
  IP_Remote_Address
     Address : NOT_FOUND
  IP_Remote Address
  Address : 192.168.1.8
```

I have this line line but it replaces only the first duplicate found:

```
awk '{print $0; if((getline nl) > 0){ print ($0!="IP_Remote_Address" && $0 == nl)? nl=$0"INSERT_NOT_FOUND_ABOVE" : nl }}' file.txt
```

I can later then use sed to replace the string `INSERT_NOT_FOUND_ABOVE"` with this:

```
sed '/INSERT_NOT_FOUND_ABOVE/i Address : NOT_FOUND' file.txt > new_file.txt
```

My only issue is that it can't detect all consecutive duplicates; it finds only the first one.

Comment: If your file can have multiple consecutive duplicates, please [edit] your example and show that.

Comment: The last IP may be missing too, right? I.e. can the last line be `IP_Remote_Address`? In that case, should "Address : NOT_FOUND" be appended after it? (Despite it not being necessarily part of two or more consecutive duplicate lines).

Comment: The last line is fine. It already has an IP Addr. Its just only on duplicates that I need to inject the line. Works perfect!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`awk`:

```
awk 'p==$0{print "     Address : NOT_FOUND"}{p=$0}1'
```

A rather naive solution.

- `p==$0` IF p == current line

  - THEN print `not found`
- `p=$0` SET p = current line
- `1`: print

Handles consecutive duplicate lines.

---

And as noted by [@san-fran](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/315749/fra-san) in comments under question, *"The last IP may be missing too, right?"* – Ups. Should have thought of that.

So:

```
awk -v e='Address : NOT_FOUND' 'p==$0{print e}{p=$0}END{if($1 ~ "IP")print e}1'
```

- Set `e` = text to inject
- `p==$0` IF p == current line

  - THEN print variable `e`
- `p=$0` SET p = current line
- `END` print `e` if current line contains `IP`
- `1`: print

Here the *error-string* has been added as a variable as we use it twice. (And trimmed for readability in this post).

Comment: Amazing!... That works for me!.. Thanks a LOT!... Im still wondering how that simple line detects the "two consecutive repeated lines" :)

Comment: @JavierGonzalez: Yes, awk is powerful. Would have liked to add a `sed` option (mostly for fun) as well, but stuck if there are consecutive duplicates.

Comment: @JavierGonzalez : in that solution, `p` is meant to mean "previous line", and is compared to `$0` (the whole current line) : if both are equal, it means we saw 2 consecutive identical lines, and we therefore `print` the `e` message (`print` will also add a newline character), before the last conditionnal ( `1`, always true ) prints the current line ( an awk line is :   `( condition) { action }`  . if action is not precised, it does the default action : print the current line if condition is true.)
The answer would be clearer (it's a bit too "golfed") by adding a few newlines here and there...

Answer (score 6):

Her is one way you could do it with a sliding-window in GNU sed:

*parse.sed*

```sed
# Handle last-line-error
$ { /IP/ s/$/\n   Address : NOT_FOUND/; }

# Always keep 2 lines in pattern-space
N

# If the lines are identical
/^([^\n]*)\n\1$/ { 

  # Add error text
  s/\n/\n   Address : NOT_FOUND\n/

  # Ensure we still only have 2 lines in pattern-space
  P
  s/[^\n]*\n//
}

# Print line 1 and delete it from pattern-space
P
D
```

Here is a modified test-text with tripple-error and last-line-error:

```
IP_Remote_Address
   Address : 192.168.1.1
IP_Remote_Address
   Address : 192.168.1.2
IP_Remote_Address
   Address : 192.168.1.3
IP_Remote_Address
IP_Remote_Address
IP_Remote_Address
IP_Remote_Address
   Address : 192.168.1.4
IP_Remote_Address
   Address : 192.168.1.5
IP_Remote_Address
   Address : 192.168.1.6
IP_Remote_Address
   Address : 192.168.1.7
IP_Remote_Address
IP_Remote_Address
   Address : 192.168.1.8
IP_Remote_Address
```

Run it like this:

```
sed -Ef parse.sed infile
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
<infile sed -E '${/IP/ s/$/\n   Address : NOT_FOUND/};N;/^([^\n]*)\n\1$/{s/\n/\n   Address : NOT_FOUND\n/;P;s/[^\n]*\n//};P;D'
```

Output in both cases:

```
IP_Remote_Address
   Address : 192.168.1.1
IP_Remote_Address
   Address : 192.168.1.2
IP_Remote_Address
   Address : 192.168.1.3
IP_Remote_Address
   Address : NOT_FOUND
IP_Remote_Address
   Address : NOT_FOUND
IP_Remote_Address
   Address : NOT_FOUND
IP_Remote_Address
   Address : 192.168.1.4
IP_Remote_Address
   Address : 192.168.1.5
IP_Remote_Address
   Address : 192.168.1.6
IP_Remote_Address
   Address : 192.168.1.7
IP_Remote_Address
   Address : NOT_FOUND
IP_Remote_Address
   Address : 192.168.1.8
IP_Remote_Address
   Address : NOT_FOUND
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the GNU version of the stream editor utility sed in its extended regex mode:

```
sed -Ee '
  x;1d;G
  ${/\n\s*IP_/ba;}
  /^(.*)\n\1$/{
    g;:a;p;c\
   Address : NOT_FOUND
    b
  }
  $!s/\n.*//
' file
```

- the current line goes to hold space and the previous line in the pattern space.
- when there is a match between hold and pattern space (meaning, previous line and current line) we print the line + the not found line.
- last line is /IP_/ then also we add the not found line.